# Blogger not showing ligatures

Tags: css, blogger, blogspot, ligature

I have enabled ligatures using both `font-feature-settings`and `font-variant-ligatures` (with all the browser-specific lines added, i.e. `-moz-`, `-ms-`, `-webkit-` and `-o-`), but ligatures just won’t display in Blogger. I’ve tried moving the CSS from html to body, but it makes no difference. the font imports correctly,¹ and looks great, but the final touch is missing. For reference, the blog’s address is [mdvuit.blogspot.com](http://mdvuit.blogspot.com), and I’m viewing it on Win10 x64 with Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit).

Here are my `html` and `body` lines (concatenated, showing only the lines without the browser prefixes) for enabling ligatures:

```
html {
    font-size: 65%;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    line-height: 2.3;

    /* here, also -moz-, -ms-, -o- and -webkit- are included */
    font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;

    /* here, also -moz-, -ms-, -o- and -webkit- are included */
    font-variant-ligatures: normal;

    /* here, also -moz-, -ms-, -o- and -webkit- are included */
    font-feature-settings: "liga", "clig";
}
```

Also, does it matter whether or not I add 1 after `liga` (et c.)? That is: `"liga" 1`, `"clig" 1` instead of as shown above.

Please, if any more information would be required, let me know.

¹ Using `@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+SC:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i|Alegreya+Sans+SC:100,100i,500,500i,800,800i|Alegreya+Sans:100,100i,500,500i,800,800i|Alegreya:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i|Cutive+Mono&subset=latin-ext';`